# How to place black stripe down non-spine side of page in book

Tags: margins, book-design

I am using the `book` class, and I have four (possibly five) pages in the middle of the book that I would like to make it easier for readers to find when flicking through.

To this end, I would like to print a 1 cm-wide black stripe down the non-spine edge of these pages (i.e. on the right-hand side of odd-numbered pages, and the left-hand side of even-numbered pages). If it is relevant, I am using Overleaf as my editor.

(I realise that most home printers cannot print right to the edge of the page, but that is not a concern here.)

Comment: see [atbegshi](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) or [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) packages

Answer (score 3):

Content can be added during page ship-out using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). The following minimal example adds a 1cm rule as required for 5 pages starting from some specific place inside the document:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcounter{blackbar}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1-50]

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{% Add content to the BackGround
  \stepcounter{blackbar}%
  \ifnum\value{blackbar}<6 % Add only 5 pages
    \AtPageLowerLeft{% Start at the Lower Left of the Page
      \ifodd\value{page}
        \hspace{\dimexpr\pdfpagewidth-1cm}% Move over to the right on odd pages
      \fi
      \rule{1cm}{\pdfpageheight}% Add vertical rule
    }%
  \fi
}
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

If you know the page number where this occurs, you can condition on the page number globally rather than placing the code inside your document content area. Alternatively, if you have no idea of how many pages you want to have the black marker for, the code could be changed to be turned on/off as needed.